# Nested GoogleMap V2 Gestures Propagation

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, zooming, gestures

I'm embeding a GooglepMap V2 into my Android APP (2.2), however when i try to make a Zoom or Navigate into the Map in my Device, the moves are too slow and sometimes the events (Zooming or Navigation) doesn't work. May i have a problem with propagating the event? which could be the problem?

Layout Map:

```
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GoogleMapActivity:

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.template);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.info);
    LinearLayout left = new LinearLayout(this);
    ...
    LinearLayout right = new LinearLayout(this);
    ...
    addMap(right);   
    l.addView(right);
}

RelativeLayout mapRelative;
private final LatLng UPV = new LatLng(39.481106, -0.340987);
private GoogleMap mapa;

public void addMap(LinearLayout main){      
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(GoogleMapActivity.this);
    mapRelative = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, null, false);
    main.addView(mapRelative);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();
    if (mapa != null) {
      mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
      mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(UPV, 15));
      mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      mapa.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
}
}
}
```

Comment: why are you adding the map twice? you already declared it as a static fragment in your xml, you dont need to add it again in your `addMap` method

Comment: i have two (2) xml, the main xml named R.layout.template (generic view for the app) and R.layout.map for a Googlemap that i want to include into the first one with addMap

Comment: but you are still adding 2 maps which is probably your problem. get rid of adding the map in code you already added it in your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! I was nesting the Map into a ScrollView with "R.layout.template". Then I remove the ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >   
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```